# In Mercurial, a .txt file is always marked as modified. Why?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Quick question:

I use Mercurial for a long term Android project and it works great. In the root level of this project, I created a file, `todo.txt`, which contains long term goals for my project.

For some reason, whenever I type `hg status` into Terminal, Mercurial always marks this `todo.txt` with an **M** for modified even when no changes were made to the file.

Anybody have a possible explanation for this harmless but bizarre occurrence?

Comment: 1. Is it single TXT-file in repo? 2. Did you try to see diff for this file 3. Do you have EOL extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the permissions on the file? Mercurial stores the executable bit for each file, it's possible that you changed that.

You cannot see this using the default settings, but you can if you do:

```
hg diff --git
```

The above uses the Git extended diff format.

You can also configure to use this format by default:

```
[diff]
git = True
```